# Android unable to browse the intranet

Tags: android, ping, intranet

## Background Info

I got a Samsung GT-S5830, running Android 2.3.4. The device has been successfully rooted.

I edited the WIFI settings to connect to my home network, so now I can surf the Internet event though there is no simm card. The network configuration is static, as follows:

```
    IP      : 192.168.0.7
    Mask    : 255.255.255.0
    Gateway : 192.168.0.1
    DNS1    : 192.168.0.1
```

In my local machine, I've installed the Android SDK tools (ADB).

From that console, I issue the following commands:

```
    1) C:\> adb shell
    2) $ su
    3) # (now successfully logged as root)
```

Once I am logged in as root (the symbol # is showing), I can successfully ping the following addresses:

```
    192.168.0.7 (the handheld address)
    192.168.0.1 (the gateway)
    127.0.0.1 (loopback)
```

I also can ping intranet sites such as Google or FB

## The problem

However, I can't ping any other machine in the intranet, eg **192.168.0.4**, which is one of my local servers.

The command **netcfg** shows the following information:

[image: netcfg output]

Did anyone had to face the same problem?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't work out what's causing the problem, but I've found a workaround.

Although the device is connected to the intranet, it make the requests from the 'outside'. As you can see in the screenshot above, the network adaptor isn't anything like 'eth0' but 'wlan0'. In other words, it's searching for the public IP of the web server

What I did is to configure the firewall to accept inbound traffic on the port 80 (web). Doing this way, I was able to render my webpages on the device.